# When a post is printed, comments should be printed too

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, printing

When a post is printed, the question and answers are printed, but the comments on them are not. It would be nice if the comments were also printed.

Comment: I think a "Printer Friendly" link would also be nice.

Comment: I am kind of anti-printer friendly. I know users have been trained to look for a printer friendly link because of abhorrent printing experiences from ill designed web sites, but with good markup and a little CSS a page should be able to just be printed.

Comment: This would be really nice.

Comment: No repro; I just printed this page out and got all three comments. Maybe this was implemented sometime in the past year? Are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: @Popular Demand - only the first 5 comments are shown.  One more here and it'll reproduce just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default only the first 5 comments are shown, and I think that's enough.

Personally, I would hate to see a lengthy list of comments most of time when printing a question.  If there are any comments that are relevant to the question or answer they're likely to be voted up and show anyway.  If you're printing precisely because you want all those comments, then it's easy to expand the comment list before printing.  Conversely, if we were to print all comments by default it would be much more difficult to hide them for those who don't want them.

Comment: This has actually fixed. At one point the CSS prevented any comments from being printed. I agree the way things are setup now is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print the question with all the answers and **all the comments** in one single printer-friendly page, check out [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/).

Comment: stackprinter is awesome. that is all.

Comment: 1 vote up for this excellent tool.